# What counts as beating a challenge in Binding of Isaac?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

I've been trying to work through the challenges introduced in [Wrath of the Lamb](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/The_Binding_of_Isaac:_Wrath_of_the_Lamb) to unlock stuff in the Binding of Issac,but have noticed that I'm not winning the challenges after beating '[It Live](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/It_Lives)s'. Do I have to also beat Sheol/Cathedral to be considered as having won the challenge, or am I encountering a glitch?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about the 10 Wrath of the Lamb challenges, the first of which is "Dark was the Night", or are you talking about achievements that unlock things?

Comment: 10 WotL challenges, sorry

Comment: OK. Which challenge in particular are you trying to beat?

Comment: Well, all of them eventually. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Yes. Different challenges have different win conditions.

Answer (score 4):

For each of the challenges, the boss that you need to beat to win the challenge is (from the wiki page):

1. Mom
2. Mom
3. Mom
4. Mom
5. Mom's Heart/It Lives
6. Mom's Heart/It Lives
7. Mom's Heart/It Lives
8. Mom's Heart/It Lives
9. Satan
10. Isaac

So for the last two challenges, beating It Lives is not sufficient for completing the challenge.

In addition, in the [most recent version](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Updates#Wrath_Of_The_Lamb_1.48) challenge 9 cannot be completed according to the wiki.

More information about challenges is on the [wiki page](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Challenges).

Comment: I was hoping for a more complete answer, I found the wiki rather lacking.

Comment: I'm not sure what more you are looking for. I told you which challenges are not completed once you have beaten It Lives.

Comment: I just don't like answers that say 'go look at the wiki', I've checked the wiki and found it didn't explain well/thouraghly enough for me.

Comment: I understand that, but what information, specifically, do you think my answer is missing?

Comment: Detail, mostly. Chill, it's not like I'm going to downvote it.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer to add some more information. Is that the detail you were looking for?